# importing data with updated parent-child keys

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, parent-child

I have a table with this structure:

```
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,

    [ParentID] [int] FOREIGN KEY([ParentID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[tblTask] ([ID])

    [Name] [varchar](20)
```

This table is populated.

I need to import data from another similar table, and need the new parent-child relationships to be valid of course. Is there some pre-existing functionality or methodology that I can use?

This is MSSQL 2008

Comment: What DBMS do you use? SQL Server, Oracle, Mimer, FoxPro, Access, ...?

Comment: What does "(" in `ID int (` mean? Is it a typo?

Comment: typo fixed. It is for SQL 2008

Comment: Will there be any other concurrent inserts happening whilst you are doing this insert? If not you can just `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON` then apply an offset to the source ids so they will end up larger than any pre-existing ids in the destination table.

Comment: @Martin: That sounds good. Add it as answer please so I can swish it! No other concurrent inserts will be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments it seems you are doing this import in an environment where you don't have to consider other concurrent inserts.

So in this case you can just `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON` then apply an offset to the source ids so they will end up larger than any pre-existing ids in the destination table.